# Add a layout into another layout into specified position

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two xml layout, LayoutOne and LayoutRow. LayoutOne contains a sort of search bar (and other widgets), and LayoutRow should contains result (single result) of search bar. Now, if no result were found, LayoutOne doesn't change and a Dialog appear, else if e result is found, i would fill LayoutRow with that result, and add it to LayoutOne (under search bar). 
It's possible to do?

Comment: you can use <include> to fill one layout inside another.Check out http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add a layout into another layout from xml. This is a way to do it:

```
  <include layout="@layout/title_bar"
       android:id="@+id/titlebar" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

In the above code, title_bar is another layout. You can add in any place in your container layout.

You can hide and show the layout as per your conditional requirement.